# Some custom operator?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I use this pattern in a lot of my functions for a Missile class:

```
class Missile
{
    Vector2 position;

    public void Launch(Vector2 towards)
    {
        Launch(Geom.AngleBetween(position, towards));
    }

    public void Launch(float angle)
    {
        ... DO THE THING
    }
}
```

Which makes me write a lot of functions 2 times, im wondering if there is a way to write them only one time with some kind of custom operator? Something like:

```
public virtual void LaunchTowards(Direction dir)
{
    ... DO THE THING
}
```

With Direction being a class with custom operator casts to automatically convert a Vector2 (towards point) or a float (angle) into a float (angle). The problem is that custom operators have to be static in C# so it seems I can't use the position variable which is necessary to convert from a point to an angle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of turning a vector into a float or vice versa, you should make `Direction` a wrapper for an angle, and allow implicit conversions from float to `Direction` and `Vector2` to `Direction`.

```
class Direction {
    public float Angle { get; private set; }

    public Direction(float angle) { this.Angle = angle; }

    public implicit operator Direction(float angle) { return new Direction(angle); }

    public implicit operator Direction(Vector2 vector) {
        return new Direction(Math.Atan(vector.Y / vector.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the property "position" of Missile with this solution, I need that property for the conversion from Vector2 to float

Comment: You don't need the position to convert a vector to float! @Krucho can't you just use the atan function?

Comment: Im already using atan in my Geom.AngleBetween function not detailed here, I need the position to calculate angle from point A -> B instead of from (0;0) -> A